# Highcharts: Column chart with pointIntervalUnit month causes incorrect spaces?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a column chart with no spaces and no overlapping between the columns based on a datetime x-axis.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: { type: 'column' },
    title: {
        text: 'Month columns'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            grouping: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        pointIntervalUnit: 'month',
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
        name: 'Test',
        negativeColor: 'rgb(223,83,83)',
        data: [{x: Date.UTC(2016,11), y:-1000},{x:Date.UTC(2017,0), y:-500}, {x:Date.UTC(2017,1), y: 500}, {x:Date.UTC(2017,2), y: 300}],
    }]
});
```

The following fiddle shows the problem:
[Spaces between columns](https://jsfiddle.net/6wtvL5x7/).

The goal is that there are no spaces in between the columns and they don't overlap. I assume that the space is caused by the changing duration of a month e.g. 30 days, 31 days, 28 days, ... but i thought this is handled by the pointIntervalUnit: month option?

Any ideas on alternative series arrangements with the expected result are highly appreciated.

Many thanks for any help on this.

Comment: There is no issue with your code; the gap is not coming from plotting. its the actual gap between your input data. ie. if you are plotting one column on 1st 2000 and another column on 1st 2017...there should be a gap. so check your input dates

Comment: @wpcoder - i'm not sure what you mean. The x values are consecutive months. The month values begin at zero, thus there are only 11 months in a year. So i have Dec 2016, Jan 2017, Feb 2018 and so on. Since my pointIntervalUnit is month i dont see a gap here or am i wrong?

Comment: @JohnDoe Didn't my answer solve your problem?!

Comment: @Yahya no, because, as Kamil mentioned in his answer, the pointWidth cant be manipulated on individual points, but nevertheless thanks for your time and good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is caused by the default `pointRange` value: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointRange

In this case it equals to 28 days - length of the shortest month - February 2017 (28 days).

There's no possibility in Highcharts to manipulate a single point using `pointRange` or  `pointWidth` (these options apply only to a series).

The easiest solution for this is simply to change the type of the x axis to `'linear'` (default) and use `categories`.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/ua4a14vu/

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to set: `pointPadding: -0.6,` i series: [JSFiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/6wtvL5x7/1/)